# Using prospective supervisor as reference for grad school application

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application

I have completed my bachelor's degree and am currently in the process of applying to graduate school for a master's degree at the same (Canadian) university.

The professor I would like to work with for my master's degree is someone I got to know during my undergraduate degree and has previously confirmed would be willing to write me a strong recommendation letter. Is having your prospective supervisor provide a recommendation letter a problem for a grad school application? On the one hand it seems like this recommendation letter would carry a lot of weight, but on the other hand I'm not sure how this would work if they are one of the people reviewing my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that given these circumstances it would be fine. You are at university A and you want to stay there and a prof from A wants to write you a letter. No problem, except that the professor may need to not otherwise have a say in your application. There might even be established rules about it.

The situation might be a bit different if you were moving to a different university (B) and want to use a recommendation from someone at B.

There are generally enough people on a committee that such minor conflicts can be resolved easily. It is even questionable if it really *is* a conflict at all. In fact, it would be difficult for students in your situation to find any recommenders at all if the profs there were off limits.

And, of course, a letter that says "I really want to work with student pmat" is pretty strong as these things go.

Comment: In some circumstances this is required. At my Uni, a prospective student looking for internal funding must have a recommendation from their prospective supervisor. The same if they are seeking research council funding.